# what is the meaning of -t in -t fileName option when connecting to a php local server

Tags: php, server, local

When I'm connecting to a local server of php on the computer and I want to change the default file of the index, I add to "php -S localhost:8000" (for example) the option "-t fileName".

I was wondering what is the meaning of "-t". I like to know when I'm reading my code to be able to transcript shortcut in my head to their real meaning, so that bother me a bit to not know ^^. (There is a lot of question with "what is the meaning of T", but I didn't find mine. Maybe I searched wrong.)

If someone knows...

Comment: try `php -h` or `php --help`

Comment: DId you try typing `man php` to see the documentation that explains all the options?

Comment: Yes I didn't think of that -_- I'm a beginner, I will think of it next time. But actually, it didn't solve my problem (just a half), because for example -i is for "i"nformation, here is clear, -d for "d"isplay, but "-t" ? because root begins by "r", not "t"... So if somebody have an idea of the word meaning by "-t" ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php):

> ```
> -t <docroot>     Specify document root <docroot> for built-in web server.
> ```

This pathname will become `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: Thank you ! You solve my problem a half, but why don-t using -r if it's for "root" (like "i" for "i"nformation), is the "t" means a word by using it ?

Comment: Ok thank you, so I guess they used the final letter of "root" instead of first.

Comment: Or they just picked a letter that wasn't already used. That's what happens frequently with Unix commands.